# Sending an image by http with node.js

Tags: image, node.js, mime-types

I'm trying to send an image by HTTP with node.js.

I can send HTML, text but, not images.

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.statusCode = response.statusCode;
        res.writeHead(res.statusCode, { 'Content-Type': response.headers['content-type'] });
        res.write(body);
        res.end();
    }
});
```

and all I get is:
[image: img not found]

The same happens when I try an icon...

If I `wget` the image I get the right content I guess, but it doesn't show up in the image viewer either... I don't know how to fix this.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is likely in `body`.  What's in there?  Are you **sure** it's a valid PNG image?  What's in `res.statusCode`?  I think you mean to put `200` there, yeah?

Comment: I updated the example so you can see how I do it.

Comment: Do you really have to download the image? Can't you just put its original src in the `img` tag?

Comment: Also, can't you just `res.writeHead( response.headers )`?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, the purpose of it is to be a proxy so yes I must pass the whole thing.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Didn't it supported that syntax. Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `body` is a buffer and not an encoded representation of the image (unless it's encoded in such a way that common browsers can decode it if you send out an appropriate `Content-Encoding` header, in which case you should (you guessed it!) send out the appropriate header.

In particular, don't try to read the image with `fs.*` methods where you asked for the responses to be UTF-8 and then try to send it "raw".

Comment: I'm actually getting it with `request` and I'm using the same headers as request sends me. Any idea about that?